# How can i translate this UDF to Pandas UDF

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I face some performance issues with this function, which aims to return `True` if a string of the string array matches with the `val` parameter. I would like to translate this into a Pandas UDF.

```
def list_contains(val):
    # Perfom what ListContains generated
  def list_contains_udf(column_list):
    for element in column_list:
      if element.startswith(val):
        return True
    return False
  return udf(list_contains_udf, BooleanType())
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: if you are using spark 2.4+, check spark sql builtin function exists:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @jxc comment, try to use the sql below in the cell of Databricks.

```
%sql
SELECT exists(column_list, element -> substr(element, 1, length(val)) == val)
```

The code `element.startswith(val)` I understand it using SQL is to take the head N ([`length(val)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#length)) length of the string `element` using [`substr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#substr) and that whether be equals the `val` self.

Otherwise, please refer to the class [`pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration(sparkSession)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration) of PySpark document to register the simiar functions as UDFs to combined use them.